# <li> height fit with content

Tags: html, css

How to make the border cover all the text content? I got the problems when the text was very long, then it will overflow the border. Thanks for any help.

```css
.fix-width
{
  width:300px;
  margin-left:auto;
  margin-right:auto;
  }
ul.obj-ans
{
  list-style-type: none;
  }
ul.obj-ans > li
{
    border: 2px solid purple;
    border-radius: 7px;
    background-color: #ffe0ff;
    padding: 5px;
    min-height: 52px;
    margin:5px auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="fix-width">
<ul class="obj-ans">
            <li>
                <div style="float:left; width:10%;">
                    A
                </div>
                <div style="float:left; width:90%;">
                    <div ng-bind-html="questionData.option1_bm" class="ng-binding"><p>Cyberjaya dilengkapi dengan kemudahan berteknologi tinggi.</p></div>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li>
                <div style="float:left; width:10%;">
                    B
                </div>
                <div style="float:left; width:90%;">
                    <div ng-bind-html="questionData.option2_bm" class="ng-binding"><p>Puan Maimunah berasa rindu kepada anaknya yang bekerja di Cyberjaya.</p></div>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li>
                <div style="float:left; width:10%;">
                    C
                </div>
                <div style="float:left; width:90%;">
                    <div ng-bind-html="questionData.option3_bm" class="ng-binding"><p>Semua murid-murid di Cyberjaya beruntung kerana mendapat pendidikan yang moden.</p></div>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li>
                <div style="float:left; width:10%;">
                    D
                </div>
                <div style="float:left; width:90%;">
                    <div ng-bind-html="questionData.option4_bm" class="ng-binding"><p>Sebanyak 50 murid mengikuti lawatan sambil belajar ke Cyberjaya.</p></div>
                </div>
            </li>
        </ul>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SIMPLE SOLUTION: Add a div element inside each li element with style **clear: both**, [clear property](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_clear.asp) specifies on which sides of an element floating elements are not allowed to float.

```
<li>
    <div style="float:left; width:10%;">
        C
    </div>
    <div style="float:left; width:90%;">
        <div ng-bind-html="questionData.option3_bm" class="ng-binding"><p>Semua murid-murid di Cyberjaya beruntung kerana mendapat pendidikan yang moden.</p></div>
    </div>
    <div style="clear:both"></div>
</li>
```

For best perfomance, clean code and SEO, I recommended to you use css classes instead inline css.

```
<li>
    <div class="first">
        C
    </div>
    <div class="second">
        <div ng-bind-html="questionData.option3_bm" class="ng-binding"><p>Semua murid-murid di Cyberjaya beruntung kerana mendapat pendidikan yang moden.</p></div>
    </div>
    <div class="clearBoth"></div>
</li>
```

In your CSS

```
.first {
   float:left; width:10%;
}

.second{
   float:left; width:90%;
}

.clearBoth{
   clear:both
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add the following:

```
height:auto;
min-height: 100%
overflow:auto;
```

See below:

```css
.fix-width
{
  width:300px;
  margin-left:auto;
  margin-right:auto;
  }
ul.obj-ans
{
  list-style-type: none;
  }
ul.obj-ans > li
{ 
height:auto;
min-height: 100%;
overflow:auto;

    border: 2px solid purple;
    border-radius: 7px;
    background-color: #ffe0ff;
    padding: 5px;
    min-height: 52px;
    margin:5px auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="fix-width">
<ul class="obj-ans">
            <li>
                <div style="float:left; width:10%;">
                    A
                </div>
                <div style="float:left; width:90%;">
                    <div ng-bind-html="questionData.option1_bm" class="ng-binding"><p>Cyberjaya dilengkapi dengan kemudahan berteknologi tinggi.</p></div>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li>
                <div style="float:left; width:10%;">
                    B
                </div>
                <div style="float:left; width:90%;">
                    <div ng-bind-html="questionData.option2_bm" class="ng-binding"><p>Puan Maimunah berasa rindu kepada anaknya yang bekerja di Cyberjaya.</p></div>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li>
                <div style="float:left; width:10%;">
                    C
                </div>
                <div style="float:left; width:90%;">
                    <div ng-bind-html="questionData.option3_bm" class="ng-binding"><p>Semua murid-murid di Cyberjaya beruntung kerana mendapat pendidikan yang moden.</p></div>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li>
                <div style="float:left; width:10%;">
                    D
                </div>
                <div style="float:left; width:90%;">
                    <div ng-bind-html="questionData.option4_bm" class="ng-binding"><p>Sebanyak 50 murid mengikuti lawatan sambil belajar ke Cyberjaya.</p></div>
                </div>
            </li>
        </ul>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Adding the **overflow:auto** property to **li** to fit the content inside the div. avoiding the overflow.
```

```css
.fix-width
{
  width:300px;
  margin-left:auto;
  margin-right:auto;
  }
ul.obj-ans
{
  list-style-type: none;
  }
ul.obj-ans > li
{
    border: 2px solid purple;
    border-radius: 7px;
    background-color: #ffe0ff;
    padding: 5px;
    min-height: 52px;
    margin:5px auto;
    overflow:auto;
}

.content{
overflow:auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="fix-width">
<ul class="obj-ans">
            <li>
                <div style="float:left; width:10%;">
                    A
                </div>
                <div style="float:left; width:90%;">
                    <div ng-bind-html="questionData.option1_bm" class="ng-binding"><p>Cyberjaya dilengkapi dengan kemudahan berteknologi tinggi.</p></div>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li>
                <div style="float:left; width:10%;">
                    B
                </div>
                <div style="float:left; width:90%;">
                    <div ng-bind-html="questionData.option2_bm" class="ng-binding"><p>Puan Maimunah berasa rindu kepada anaknya yang bekerja di Cyberjaya.</p></div>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li>
                <div style="float:left; width:10%;">
                    C
                </div>
                <div style="float:left; width:90%;">
                    <div ng-bind-html="questionData.option3_bm" class="ng-binding"><p>Semua murid-murid di Cyberjaya beruntung kerana mendapat pendidikan yang moden.</p></div>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li>
                <div style="float:left; width:10%;">
                    D
                </div>
                <div style="float:left; width:90%;">
                    <div ng-bind-html="questionData.option4_bm" class="ng-binding"><p>Sebanyak 50 murid mengikuti lawatan sambil belajar ke Cyberjaya.</p></div>
                </div>
            </li>
        </ul>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just remove your fixed min height from list tag or else make it auto min-height and add overflow:auto; which will work as your requirement.

```css
.fix-width
{
  width:300px;
  margin-left:auto;
  margin-right:auto;
  }
ul.obj-ans
{
  list-style-type: none;
  }
ul.obj-ans > li
{
    border: 2px solid purple;
    border-radius: 7px;
    background-color: #ffe0ff;
    padding: 5px;
    margin:5px auto;
    overflow:auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="fix-width">
<ul class="obj-ans">
            <li>
                <div style="float:left; width:10%;">
                    A
                </div>
                <div style="float:left; width:90%;">
                    <div ng-bind-html="questionData.option1_bm" class="ng-binding"><p>Cyberjaya dilengkapi dengan kemudahan berteknologi tinggi.</p></div>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li>
                <div style="float:left; width:10%;">
                    B
                </div>
                <div style="float:left; width:90%;">
                    <div ng-bind-html="questionData.option2_bm" class="ng-binding"><p>Puan Maimunah berasa rindu kepada anaknya yang bekerja di Cyberjaya.</p></div>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li>
                <div style="float:left; width:10%;">
                    C
                </div>
                <div style="float:left; width:90%;">
                    <div ng-bind-html="questionData.option3_bm" class="ng-binding"><p>Semua murid-murid di Cyberjaya beruntung kerana mendapat pendidikan yang moden.</p></div>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li>
                <div style="float:left; width:10%;">
                    D
                </div>
                <div style="float:left; width:90%;">
                    <div ng-bind-html="questionData.option4_bm" class="ng-binding"><p>Sebanyak 50 murid mengikuti lawatan sambil belajar ke Cyberjaya.</p></div>
                </div>
            </li>
        </ul>
  </div>
```